# Problems constructing a MasterCard Gen AC command

Tags: emv

I'm trying to construct a generate AC command for a Mastercard contactless card. I believe I have correctly read the information the card requires for this, from the CDOL1, and send it, with the correct length in a Generate AC command, however the correct is replying with a 6700 (wrong length command). Any advice on what the problem is would be very much appreciated.

The CDOL1 provide by the card is:

```
  8C | len:27    Card Risk Management Data Object List 1 (CDOL1)
    9F02 | len:06   Amount, Authorised (Numeric)
    9F03 | len:06   Amount, Other (Numeric)
    9F1A | len:02   Terminal Country Code
      95 | len:05   Terminal Verification Results
    5F2A | len:02   Transaction Currency Code
      9A | len:03   Transaction Date
      9C | len:01   Transaction Type
    9F37 | len:04   Unpredictable Number
    9F35 | len:01   Terminal Type
    9F45 | len:02   Data Authentication Code
    9F4C | len:08   ICC Dynamic Number
    9F34 | len:03   Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Results
    9F21 | len:03   Transaction Time HHMMSS
    9F7C | len:14   Customer Exclusive Data (CED)
```

For which I'm providing the values

```
    Amount, Authorised (Numeric)    000000000100
    Amount Other (Numeric)          000000000000
    Terminal Country Code           0826         
    Terminal Verification Results   0000000000   
    Transaction Currency Code       0826         
    Transaction Date                190819       
    Transaction Type                00           
    Unpredictable Number            3357A30A
    Terminal Type                   21           
    Data Authentication Code        0000
    ICC Dynamic Number              0000000000000000   
    Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Results 1F0302 
    Transaction Time                120505
    Customer Exclusive Data (CED)   0000000000000000000000000000
```

which is a total of 60 (3C) bytes, adding the Gen AC header and the Le my message is then:

```
   80AE50003C000000000100000000000000082600000000000826190819003357A30A21000000000000000000001F03021205050000000000000000000000000000
```

However, the card always returns 6700, which as I understanding it indicates the wrong length. I've tried some other values and dropping the Le, however, I don't see how these could affect the length.

A full trace of my run (with some values Xed out) is:

```
Sending 00A404000E325041592E5359532E4444463031
response length: 62
status: 9000
  6F | len:3A    File Control Information (FCI) Template
  84 | len:14    DF Name: 325041592E5359532E4444463031
  A5 | len:28    Proprietary Information
    BF0C | len:25    File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Data
          61 | len:23    Directory Entry
              4F | len:7    Application Identifier (AID): A0000000041010
              50 | len:10    Application Label: 4D617374657243617264
              87 | len:1    Application Priority Indicator: 01
            9F0A | len:8    Application Selection Registered Proprietary Data list: 0001050400000000

Sending 00A4040007A0000000041010
response length: 81
status: 9000
  6F | len:4D    File Control Information (FCI) Template
      84 | len:7    DF Name: A0000000041010
  A5 | len:42    Proprietary Information
      50 | len:10    Application Label: 4D617374657243617264
    9F12 | len:10    Application Preferred Name: 4D617374657243617264
      87 | len:1    Application Priority Indicator: 01
    9F11 | len:1    Issuer Code Table Index: 01
    5F2D | len:2    Language Preference: 656E
    BF0C | len:1A    File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Data
        9F4D | len:2    Log Entry: 0B0A
        9F6E | len:7    Form Factor Indicator (qVSDC): 08260000303000
        9F0A | len:8    Application Selection Registered Proprietary Data list: 0001050400000000

Sending 80A8000002830000
response length: 22
status: 9000
  77 | len:12    Response Message Template Format 2
  82 | len:2    Application Interchange Profile: 1980
  94 | len:12    Application File Locator: 080101001001010120010200

Sending 00B2011400
response length: 171
status: 9000
  70 | len:81    Record Template
       9F42 | len:2    Application Currency Code: 0826
       5F25 | len:3    Application Effective Date YYMMDD: XXXXXX
       5F24 | len:3    Application Expiration Date YYMMDD: XXXXXX
         5A | len:8    Application Primary Account Number (PAN): XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
       5F34 | len:1    Application Primary Account Number (PAN) Sequence Number: 00
       9F07 | len:2    Application Usage Control: FF00
       9F08 | len:2    Application Version Number: 0002
  8C | len:27    Card Risk Management Data Object List 1 (CDOL1)
    9F02 | len:06   Amount, Authorised (Numeric)
    9F03 | len:06   Amount, Other (Numeric)
    9F1A | len:02   Terminal Country Code
      95 | len:05   Terminal Verification Results
    5F2A | len:02   Transaction Currency Code
      9A | len:03   Transaction Date
      9C | len:01   Transaction Type
    9F37 | len:04   Unpredictable Number
    9F35 | len:01   Terminal Type
    9F45 | len:02   Data Authentication Code
    9F4C | len:08   ICC Dynamic Number
    9F34 | len:03   Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Results
    9F21 | len:03   Transaction Time HHMMSS
    9F7C | len:14   Customer Exclusive Data (CED)
  8D | len:0C    Card Risk Management Data Object List 2 (CDOL2)
      91 | len:0A   Issuer Authentication Data
      8A | len:02   Authorisation Response Code
      95 | len:05   Terminal Verification Results
    9F37 | len:04   Unpredictable Number
    9F4C | len:08   ICC Dynamic Number
  8E | len:14    Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) List: 000000000000000042031E031F03
9F0D | len:5    Issuer Action Code - Default: B450840000
9F0E | len:5    Issuer Action Code - Denial: 0000000000
9F0F | len:5    Issuer Action Code - Online: B470848000
5F28 | len:2    Issuer Country Code: 0826
9F4A | len:1    Static Data Authentication Tag List: 82
  57 | len:19    Track 2 Equivalent Data: ...

Sending 00B2010C00
response length: 112
status: 9000
  70 | len:6C    Record Template
    9F6C | len:2    Card Transaction Qualifiers (CTQ): 0001
    9F62 | len:6    PCVC3 Track1 location: 000000380000
    9F63 | len:6    PUNATC Track1 location: 00000000E0E0
      56 | len:43    Track 1 Equivalent Data: ...
    9F64 | len:1    NATC Track1 location: 03
    9F65 | len:2    PCVC3 Track2 location: 000E
    9F66 | len:2    PUNATC Track2 location: 0E70
    9F6B | len:19    Track1 data: ...
    9F67 | len:1    NATC Track2 location: 03

Sending 00B2012400
response length: 189
status: 9000
  70 | len:81    Record Template
    9F47 | len:1    ICC Public Key Expo: 03
    9F46 | len:176    ICC Public Key Cert: 8A4...C3

Sending 00B2022400
response length: 229
status: 9000
  70 | len:81    Record Template
      8F | len:1    Certification Authority Public Key Index: 05
    9F32 | len:1    Issuer Public Key Exponent: 03
      92 | len:36    Issuer Public Key Remainder: EEAAE75B30426DEB86F113DFD1B53E7D98D6456172ECFA87F83A3E7733341572B1AC1CE9
      90 | len:176    Issuer Public Key Certificate: 3E9C8727E2...2FAF87606

Sending  80AE50003C000000000100000000000000082600000000000826190819003357A30A21000000000000000000001F03021205050000000000000000000000000000
response length: 2
Error: 6700
```

I would have expected the reply to the final command to be the AC, or an error with one of the inputs, not a 6700 length error message.

Answer (score 5):

You read the 9F7C length wrong. It's 0x14 not 14 decimal. The length for this card application should be 66 (0x42).

What you might want to also know is that ICCPK cert contains PAN as well so you haven't Xed out enough (516273******2854). Since you are trying to make a CDA transaction, you should learn more about that during public key retrieval.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the problem. Changing the length of the Merchant Custom Data for 14 to 20 gets it working. Thanks also for you concern about the PAN however this is a not an active card, its just used for testing. I'd upvote your answer however I do not have enough reputation.